# CORS error while making post request to logstash

Tags: angularjs, linux, http, nginx, cors

I have configured Logstash 1.5.2 to consume http input on a linux machine.

This is my logstash input configuration:

```
input {
        http {
                host => "10.x.x.120"
                port => "8500"
        }
}
```

I can send data to logstash by using curl -XPOST from the linux machine.

But when I make a $http.post(url, postData); request from my angularJS application I get the following error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource

I have hosted my application on the same linux machine using nginx within a docker container.
I have tried to configure nginx to allow CORS by adding the following lines to the nginx.conf:

```
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
```

But still the error persists.

Also when I hit http://10.x.x.120:8500 from my browser address bar I get 'ok'.

[image]
[image]
Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: If you do `curl -i http://10.x.x.120:8500` do the headers actually say `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`?

Comment: No is doesn't show it there in headers. This is all I get http/1.1 200 ok - content-type:text/plain - content-length: 2

Comment: Then it looks like your nginx configuration is wrong. [See this for a sample CORS config for nginx.](http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html)

Comment: Yup I tried these settings but this doesn't work. I still get the same header info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this running by using reverse-proxy setting for nginx.

I modified my URL to be as follows:
http://10.x.x.120/logs

And then made the following changes to the nginx.conf file:

```
location^~ /logs {
    proxy_pass http://10.x.x.120:8500; 
}
```

Now when ever my application makes an HTTP POST request to http://10.x.x.120:8500/logs it is redirected to http://10.x.x.120:8500.

Voila!! Logstash gets the data because it is listening to port 8500.

Answer (score 2):

This could be a solution depending on your setup of [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/introduction.html) in our case we use the [http](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-http.html#plugins-inputs-http-response_headers) plugin to accept http calls.
[The **http** plugin plugin supports the following configuration options](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-http.html#_synopsis_15):

```
http {
    response_headers {
        "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" => "*",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need not only to configure the POST/GET but OPTIONS as well, this is the configuration that I've in production and is working

```
#
# Wide-open CORS config for nginx
#
location / {
     if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        #
        # Om nom nom cookies
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        #
        # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
        #
        # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 200;
     }
     if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
     }
     if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks @maurycy I have tired this but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show more of the error, maybe a screenshot from your network tab to see what's going on?

Comment: adding 200 to options doesn't change anything. I till get the CORS error.

Comment: Did you restarted nginx? Are you using correct server? from the screenshot I can see that `OPTIONS` call is made properly but response headers DO NOT show any of the headers that should be set on the nginx side

Comment: Yes I restarted nginx. The response is coming from logstash service running on the linux machine, where as nginx is inside a docker container on the same machine.

Comment: this is my plunker that I used for different answer but it does a CORS call to my server (in that case is standard LAMP) but look at the headers of OPTIONS call http://plnkr.co/edit/YOzP2VCPOXwh4qoQC73i?p=preview

Comment: Should we move to chat for more discussion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83565/discussion-between-droidarrrh-and-maurycy).

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple work around for this.
Use logstash input plugin to open up two ports

- say 5544 without credentials setup and "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" => "*"
- say 5545 with credentials

then forward the requests coming from open port 5544 (without authentication) to 5545 with Authorization headers so that requests are secured.

```
output {
  if [headers][http_host] == "localhost:5544" {
    http {
      url => "http://127.0.0.1:5545"
      retry_failed => false
      http_method => ["post"]
      headers => ["Authorization", "%{authKey}"]
   }
  } else if [headers][http_host] =~ ":5545"  {
    elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
    http_compression => "true"
    }
  }
```